# How to get drawable path?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
        public async Task<List<AppItem>> GetAndroidApps()
        {
            try
            {
                var apps = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MatchAll);

                foreach(var item in apps)
                {
                    string packageName = item.PackageName;
                    string appName = item.LoadLabel(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager);
                    var appIcon = item.LoadIcon(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager).ToString();

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{appIcon}; {appName}; {packageName};");
                }

                return null;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

How I can get appIcon path to display it?
I can't get full path to other app icon...

Thank you!

Best wishes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the icon from the drawable resource identifier (in the package's resources) of this component's. And set the imagesource for imageview.

I use my App6 for example to load the icon. It works.

```
var apps = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MatchAll);

        foreach (var item in apps)
        {
            string packageName = item.PackageName;
            string appName = item.LoadLabel(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager);

            if (packageName == "com.companyname.app6")
            {
                var appIcon = item.LoadIcon(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager).ToString();
                var image = item.Icon;
                imageView.SetImageResource(image);
            }


            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{appIcon}; {appName}; {packageName};");
        }
```

**Updated:**

You could use the DependentService to do that.

I convet the resID of deawable to bitmap and then convert the bitmap to stream. At last, i set the image source form the stream in Xamarin.forms.

Create the interface in Xamarin.forms.

```
 public interface GetIcon
{
    byte[] GetIconFromApp();
}
```

Implementation in Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetIconFromApp_Android))]
namespace App13.Droid
{
class GetIconFromApp_Android : GetIcon
{
    public byte[] GetIconFromApp()
    {
        var apps = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MatchAll);
        byte[] bitmapData=null;
        foreach (var item in apps)
        {
            string packageName = item.PackageName;
            string appName = item.LoadLabel(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager);

            if (packageName == "com.companyname.app6")
            {
                var appIcon = item.LoadIcon(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager).ToString();
                var imageID = item.Icon;

                // Converting Drawable Resource to Bitmap
                var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Forms.Context.Resources, imageID);

                //comver bitmap to byte
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                    bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
                }

            }



        }
        return bitmapData;

    }
}
}
```

Platform implementations with button click event.

```
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ImageByteArray = DependencyService.Get<GetIcon>().GetIconFromApp();
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(ImageByteArray, 0, ImageByteArray.Length));
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How I can display this in XF Image View?

Comment: Glad to help. Do not forget to accept as answer. Thanks~